# Find top 2 employees with longest work experience for each salary range

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have two tables.

Salary_Grade

| GRADE | Min_Salary | Max_Salary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 2100 | 3600 |
| 13 | 3601 | 4200 |
| 14 | 4201 | 6000 |
| 15 | 6001 | 9000 |
| 16 | 9001 | 30000 |

Employees

| EMPLOYEE_NO | NAME | HIRE_DATE | SALARY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1007 | SMITH | 2016-02-20 00:00:00.000 | 15000 |
| 2340 | JOHNSON | 2018-02-07 00:00:00.000 | 3300 |
| 2341 | WILLIAMS | 2019-10-11 00:00:00.000 | 3750 |
| 2345 | BROWN | 2018-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 8925 |
| 2355 | JONES | 2015-07-13 00:00:00.000 | 8550 |
| 3434 | GARCIA | 2011-08-11 00:00:00.000 | 7350 |
| 4356 | MILLER | 2013-10-12 00:00:00.000 | 3750 |
| 4455 | DAVIS | 2000-04-30 00:00:00.000 | 2850 |
| 4456 | WILSON | 1980-03-03 00:00:00.000 | 9000 |
| 4467 | ANDERSON | 2001-07-28 00:00:00.000 | 3900 |
| 5643 | THOMAS | 2011-03-10 00:00:00.000 | 4800 |
| 6538 | TAYLOR | 2011-08-11 00:00:00.000 | 9000 |
| 6578 | MOORE | 2020-11-27 00:00:00.000 | 2400 |
| 8900 | LEE | 2015-03-03 00:00:00.000 | 4500 |

My task is to display the two employees with the longest work experience, for each GRADE (the grade is results from the salary range in the SALARY_GRADE  and the corresponding SALARY from the EMPLOYEE table)

Expected result:

| GRADE | NAME | EXPERIENCE(DAYS) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | JOHNSON | 1359 |
| 12 | DAVIS | 7851 |
| 13 | MILLER | 2938 |
| 13 | ANDERSON | 7397 |
| 14 | THOMAS | 3885 |
| 14 | LEE | 2431 |
| 15 | WILSON | 15214 |
| 15 | TAYLOR | 3731 |
| 16 | SMITH | 2077 |

I created table `EMPLOYEE_SALGRADE` with employee id and salary grades connected to them

```
   CREATE TABLE [EMPLOYEE_SALGRADE](

   [GRADE_NO] [int]  not null,
   [EMPLOYEE_NO] [int]  not null,
   FOREIGN KEY (Grade_NO) REFERENCES Salary_Grade(grade),
   FOREIGN KEY (Employee_NO) REFERENCES Employee(Employee_NO))

   insert into EMPLOYEE_SALGRADE(GRADE_NO, EMPLOYEE_NO)
   SELECT s.grade, e.EMPLOYEE_NO FROM employee as e,salary_grade as s
   WHERE e.salary BETWEEN s.min_salary AND s.max_salary
   order by e.salary'
```

and added column Experience to Employee table

```
Alter table Employee
add Experience as  DATEDIFF(dd,Hire_date,getdate())
```

Now I'm trying with subquery

```
select  s.GRADE, e.NAME,  e.Experience
from SALARY_GRADE as S
join EMPLOYEE_SALGRADE AS ES
ON S.GRADE=es.GRADE_NO
join EMPLOYEE as e 
on es.Employee_no=e.EMPLOYEE_NO
where Experience in (select top 2(experience) from EMPLOYEE group by Experience)
```

But this not correct result

Comment: I've removed the tag [[tag:mysql]] as this uses brackets (`[]`) to delimit identify, which is what T-SQL uses. If you *are* using MySQL, you should be using backticks (`\``).

Comment: Side note: It's **2021**, it's *long* past time you adopted the use of the ANSI-92 explicit JOIN syntax in all your statements, not just some of them.

Comment: For your subquery, a `TOP 2` with no `ORDER BY` will mean that 2 **arbitrary** rows will be returned. These rows could be different *every time* the query is run. Adding some expected results here will likely help us help you.

Comment: I would recommend that you look at RANK: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 0):

I did some research, and the correct answer is:

```
select * from ( select  s.GRADE, e.NAME,  e.Experience,  row_number() over (partition by s.grade order by e.experience desc) as employee_rank
from SALARY_GRADE as S
join EMPLOYEE_SALGRADE AS ES
ON S.GRADE=es.GRADE_NO
join EMPLOYEE as e 
on es.Employee_no=e.EMPLOYEE_NO) ranks
where employee_rank <= 2;
```